# Which punctuation should be used on an error page?

Tags: meta, custom-error-pages, punctuation

Should it be

> The page could not be found

or

> The page could not be found.

?

With proper Oxford English the later would be the obvious choice but there are many examples for the first one out there as well.

Answer (score 1):

What does your company's coding standard outline? Generally, this is the kind of thing a coding standard or business practice should address. There is no "right" choice.

That being said, obviously, the second one with the period. I base this on nothing but my personal preference.